# jQuery context when context is instanceof jQuery

Tags: jquery

When I call $ function as usual with only selector passed:

```
  $("p");
```

It as expected, returns jQuery object wrapped with fn.prototype methods. That object is also Array with one property - selector context.

But, when I change context:

```
$("p",document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0]);
```

jQuery returns empty array ? Why is that ?
I guess something happens when **selector context** is not **document**, but I don't understand what.

Is the answer in this line ?

```
context = context instanceof jQuery ? context[0] : context;
```

Comment: This `context` parameter restricts jQuery to only search for `p`'s which are descendants of `document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0]`... what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I don't understand why returned array is empty ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is equivalent to

```
$("h1:first").find("p");
```

This will find all P objects inside a H1 tag. And since no objects are found, you will see an empty array returned. jQuery always returns an empty array when it does not find objects for a specified selector